# Необходимо отформатировать суммы на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, валидация

имеется следующая задача: на страницу выводятся много сумм, необходимо сделать так, чтобы они отображались в удобочитаемом виде (напр. 10 000, а не 10000, как сейчас). Пробовал `jquery` - почему-то не видит этих `span`, в которых находится сумма. Как это можно реализовать? Была идея просто заменить значение `$('.myTag').val()` с помощью метода `.toLoacaleString("ru-RU")`, но я не могу получить значение этих тегов.

Comment: Не знаю, важго это или нет, но страница (все что в `body`) приходит в зашифрованном виде, а head - нет, так как в head как раз скрипты для расшифровки

Comment: Сложно сказать, когда ничего не известно. Сначала надо разобраться почему он "не видит спаны", а это к вопросу форматирования сумм не относится.